# User registration in a web application using Xpages

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino

I've searched "everywherE" and there's so little if any information about this subject, so thought I'd ask the pros and everyone like me can benefit.
Anyways, I'm building an application which needs users to be registered to create documents and make various actions through the application.
Now the user registration shouldn't be anything new and unseen, I need the proper or the best way or whatever way you handle user registration.
When the user enters data and presses Sign up, they should receive and automatic email containing a link to confirm their Signing up and than when they login in the application they'll have the rights assigned to the user group for example called "Basic users".
Also, the forgot password option?

How do you make a basic user registration handling?

Comment: Perhaps this might be something for you to start from
[openntf project User self register](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20User%20Selfregister%20and%20Avatar%20App)

Answer (score 3):

This OpenNTF project has also a user self registration: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=LotusPeople

Answer (score 3):

My blog post on registering users from Facebook might be of some use... http://mattwhite.me/blog/2010/10/20/how-to-get-sso-for-facebook-working-with-xpages.html

Matt

Comment: this looks pretty nice but I don't need Facebook at this point. But I'll bookmark the link :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have also taken the OpenNtf project for self register (from younotes) and changed it a bit.  It works great.